# Principle of Mathematical induction proof

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

> **Prove that $2^n >n$ for all positive integer $n.$**

I know this can be easily proved by using **PMI** 
Let **$P(n): 2^n > n$**

For $n = 1$ $$2^1 > 1.$$ Hence $P(1)$ is true.

Assuming that $P(k)$ is true for any positive integer $k$ i.e.

**$$P(K) = 2^k > k$$**

**we shall now prove that $P(k+1)$ is true whenever $P(k)$ is true.**

$P(k+1)$:  $$2 \cdot 2^k > k+1$$

Now I'm unable to deduce anything from my last step to prove it. Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **use the induction hypothesis**, i.e. use the fact that $2^k>k$ in your proof that $2\cdot2^k>k+1$.

The induction hypothesis says
$$
2^k >k.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $2$ you get
$$
2^{k+1}>2k.
$$
Then we have
$$
2^{k+1} > 2k = k+k \ge k+1
$$
and so
$$
2^{k+1} > k+1,
$$
which was to be shown.

Comment: What have you done here " Now it's enough to prove $2k\ge k+1$. But $2k = k+ k\ge k+1$ since $k\ge1$?" I don't know why but it's not clicking me.

Comment: @user109256 : I've rephrased it.  Take a look. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

See $2^k>k$ so $2^{k+1}>2k$ now we know for positive values $2k>k+1$,for $k>1$ thus the result.

Comment: Not for $k=1$ :)

Comment: Thanks that was the base case so I didn't mention

Answer (score 0):

Let $S(n)$ be the statement: $2^{n}>n$; $n\in{\mathbb{Z}}$

Basis step: $S(0)$:

LHS: $2^{0}=1$

RHS: $(0)=0$

$\hspace{75 mm}$LHS $>$ RHS $\hspace{1 mm}$(verified.)

Inductive step:

Assume $S(k)$ is true, i.e. assume that $2^{k}>k$; $k\in{\mathbb{Z}}$

$\hspace{59 mm}\Rightarrow2 \bullet{2^{k}}>2k$

$\hspace{59 mm}\Rightarrow 2^{k+1}>2k=k+k$

$\hspace{73.5 mm}>k+1$

So, $S(k+1)$ is true whenever $S(k)$ is true.

Therefore, $2^{n}>n$; $n\in{\mathbb{Z}}$.